# Recursive Maximum Subsequence Sum With No Three Consective Elements

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am attempting to solve, using recursion a way to maximize sub sequence sum such that no three elements are consecutive.

There is a way to do this by dynamic programming but I want to build on it using recursion first.

Some sample input and outputs:

```
Input:{1, 2, 3}
Output: 5

Input:{100, 1000, 100, 1000, 1}
Output: 2101

Input:{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
Output: 27
```

I am able to get mostly correct results apart from the second one {100, 1000, 100, 1000, 1}.

My solution:

```
int maxSubsequenceSum(vector<int> nums)
{
    return helper(nums, nums.size());
}

int helper(vector<int>& nums, int index)
{
    if (index <= 0) return 0;

    int withoutThird = helper(nums, index - 3) + nums[index - 1] + nums[index - 2];
    int withoutSecond = helper(nums, index - 3) + (index - 1 < 0 ? 0 : nums[index - 1]) + (index - 3 < 0 ? 0 : nums[index - 3]);
    int withoutFirst = helper(nums, index - 3) + (index - 2 < 0 ? 0 : nums[index - 2]) + (index - 3 < 0 ? 0 : nums[index - 3]);
    return max(withoutThird, max(withoutSecond, withoutFirst));
}
```

Individually the three **withoutThird**, **withoutSecond** and **withoutFirst** give the correct result only whilst in a recursive arrangement it fails. Why does it fail and is this a correct recursive approach?

Comment: one error that I can point out is that your code won't consider alternate elements in the sequence. Meaning that if the optimal choice is of selecting alternate elements, then this won't work. As such, you might want to try another recursive approach based on the lines of recursive implementation of Longest Increasing subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`withoutSecond` and `withoutFirst` has some bugs. To make it simpler, let's assume `index >= 3`. Look at `withoutSecond`:

```
withoutSecond = helper(nums, index - 3) + nums[index - 1] + nums[index - 3]
```

It picks `index-1` and `index-3`. So if we pick `index-4` in `helper(nums, index - 3)` then we can not pick `index-5`, but it contains in `withoutThird` in function `helper(nums, index - 3)`. That would yield a **larger** result than expected.

---

### Algorithm

As the condition is does not allow **3** consecutive elements. So we only need to consider **2** consecutive  elements to decide if we should pick another or not.

Suppose `f(a, n)` calculates largest result of array `a` with size `n`.

1. If does **not** pick `a[n]`: `f(a, n) -> f(a, n-1)`
2. If pick `a[n]` && pick `a[n-1]`: `f(a, n) -> f(a, n-3) + a[n] + a[n-1]`
3. If pick `a[n]` && **not** pick `a[n-1]`: `f(a, n) -> f(a, n-2) + a[n]`

OK, that's all the 3 cases.

---

### Code

See the following code for details

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

// this runs slow
// but you can use memorized search to speed up the process
int helper(vector<int>& nums, int index) {
    if (index == 0) return 0;
    if (index == 1) return nums[0];
    if (index == 2) return nums[0] + nums[1];

    int without_last_1                 = helper(nums, index-1);
    int with_last_1_and_2              = helper(nums, index-3) + nums[index-1] + nums[index-2];
    int with_last_1_and_without_last_2 = helper(nums, index-2) + nums[index-1];

    return max(without_last_1, max(with_last_1_and_2, with_last_1_and_without_last_2));
}

int maxSubsequenceSum(vector<int> nums) {
    return helper(nums, nums.size());
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", maxSubsequenceSum({1, 2, 3}));
    printf("%d\n", maxSubsequenceSum({100, 1000, 100, 1000, 1}));
    printf("%d\n", maxSubsequenceSum({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now with my code. I will test this out tomorrow and get back with results.

Comment: shouldn't it be f(a, n) -> f(a, n-3) + a[n] + a[n-1] in the second case

Comment: @marvel308 Yes. Sorry for my typo. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to get maximum with **no three consecutive elements**.

What you are doing is, taking 3 elements at a time, select two having maximum sum from it, add them and so on.

---

Taking one example :-  

`Input : {A, B, C, D, E, F}`

As your recursion goes right to left. 
Assume, taking, {D, E, F} 
`(D + E) > (E + F) and (D + E) > (D + F)` 
Your code will select `{D, E}` from last 3 elements. 
 
Now, taking, {A, B, C} 
 Assuming,
`(B + C) > (A + B) and (B + C) > (A + C)` 
Your code will select `{B, C}` from first 3 elements.

Total Selected Elements = {B, C, D, E}. 
Noticed Something? 
**You ended up adding four continuous elements.**

---

One short example : {100, 1000, 100, 1000, 1} 
2 windows : [0,1] and [2,4] 
Selected {100, 1000} from [2, 4] 
and Selected {100, 1000} from [0, 1] 
Added up four continuos elements.
 Got: 2200, which is your actual output.

---

Hint: Try to pass the element index which u didn't add from one state of recursion to another. If still stuck, comment and I will write a similar code :)